# Spinning suspended magnets question

Tags: electromagnetism

Imagine you have 2 donut magnets on a stick (a classic setup for science class) in which the two magnets are separated by the same pole repulsion. imagine also that this setup is inside a hard vacuum. now, assume that we have an unrealistic but ideal situation in which the upper magnet is spinning but is also stable such that it does not move in any plane relative to the lower magnet, it only spins and never touches the stick.  In this hypothetical case, in a vacuum, what would slow the upper magnet's spin?

Comment: I'm surprised no one has attempted to answer this yet. Maybe i should put it another way. If one places a natural magnet in close proximity to one or more other natural magnets of opposing poles so that it is suspended (in a vacuum), negating friction, what will slow the spinning magnet down? Would the opposing field lines themselves cause any sort of drag?  In my hypothetical setup I chose 2 opposing donut magnets for a continuous rotating field around a circle to avoid magnetic locking. Negating friction and wobble would the upper donut magnet spin indefinitely?

Comment: By the way I'm not suggesting that this setup is feasible with regards to friction and wobble.  Those variables can be at least minimized but probably not eliminated with natural magnets.  I'm just trying to understand what force would slow such a spinning magnet down other than friction. Using something like a radial configuration of disc magnets will cause a locking effect which is well known. The only system I see working is one in which only 2 magnets are in constant opposition to one another while one is spinning.  Donuts were all I could conceive.